# Can we make the registered vote arrow more obvious on meta-se?

Tags: feature-request, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could the voted/unvoted button artwork be further differentiated on meta.apple?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/could-the-voted-unvoted-button-artwork-be-further-differentiated-on-meta-apple)

I must be getting old. I have a hard time telling when I've voted on meta questions. The registered vote arrow is too close in contrast to the unregistered vote arrow.

[image: Registered vs. unregistered vote arrows]